# Show that $\deg(fg) = m+n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$, a ring with a $1$ and $f,g$ two polynomials, where $\deg(f)=n, \deg(g)=m$. 
Also, there's a $c\in R$ such that $b_mc = 1$. Show that $\deg(fg)=m+n$.

I'd be glad for a guidance.

Thanks

Comment: What is this $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and also $b_m$ ? Maybe $c \in R$...

Comment: $b_m$ is the coefficient of $x^m$. What isn't clear about $c\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AlonAlon so $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^m b_k x^k$ and $c\in R$ to fix things, right? This still is bogus; it doesn't even hold for $R = \mathbb R$ with the natural operations.
$$\deg(f+g) = \max(m,n) \text{ iff } b_{\max(m,n)} + a_{\max(m,n)} \ne 0$$

Comment: As a hint, consider $f(X), g(X) = tX + 1$ over the ring $R = \mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^2)$.

Comment: @AlonAlon And I bet you mean $deg(fg)$ not $deg(f+g)$ right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $c\in R$. My bad. Now the question is correct.

Comment: @brick, You right

Comment: @AlonAlon Let $a_m \neq 0$ be the leading coefficient of $g$. Then the leading coefficient of $fg$ is $b_ma_m$ (this is the coefficient of $x^{m+n}$). Could it be $0$, since $b_m$ is invertible?

Comment: @brick It could be if $0=1$ ($R=\{0\})$

Comment: @AlonAlon and then all the polynomials will be of degree $-\infty$ :D

Comment: Right, Thank you @brick!

Comment: @AlonAlon no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One always has $\deg(fg)\leq\deg(f)+\deg(g)=n+m$ since all products of terms contributing to the product $fg$ satisfy this degree inequality. Also there is only one product of terms contributing in degree $n+m$, namely the product $a_nx^n.b_mx^m=a_nb_mx^{n+m}$ of the leading terms, so no additive cancellation of contributions is possible: one has $\deg(fg)=n+m$ is and only if $a_nb_m\neq0$. But since $a_n\neq0$ (by the definition of degree) and $b_m$ is invertible (so not a zero divisor), the latter condition is always true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
You only need to show that $(fg)_{m+n} \ne 0$ is the leading coefficient. To do that look at
$$fg(x) = \left( \sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{k=0}^m b_k x^k \right)$$
Note that all coefficients of power $> n+m$ must be $0$, so this shows $\deg(fg) = \deg f + \deg g$.

Comment: Formally it is only a leading coefficient _if_ it is nonzero. It is however always the coefficient of $x^{m+n}$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Well, you are supposed to prove that ^^ Reviewing the wording here